# Why is my image height not fitting into the parent div correctly?

Tags: css

I'm having a rough time trying to position things in CSS.  I understand padding,margin,height,width which to me seems like it should be enough to organize nested div boxes, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be that easy for me.

Anyway, in my example below, the profile picture is bigger than the actual div it's contained in.

What am I doing wrong here?

## CSS

```
.mailcontainer{
    top: 40px;
    width:600px;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color:green;
}


.mail {
  margin: 5px auto;
  width: 700px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.leftprofileimage img {
  float: left;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 90px;
}

.snippet {
  float: right;
  top: 10px;
  width: 55%;
  margin-left:26%;
  position: absolute;
}

.sendername {
    font-size: 1.0em;
    width: 26%;
    padding: 9px 0;
    margin-left: 15%;
    position: absolute;
  }
```

## HTML

```
 <div class="mailcontainer">
    <div class="mail">
      <div class="leftprofileimage"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/BodegaMagazine/StaffPhotos/Small/eric-small-profile-photo.jpeg" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="sendername"><a href="/">Jeff
      </a></div>
      <div class="snippet">
      Hello this is a test message</div>
      <div class="delete"><p>DELETE</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mail">
      <div class="leftprofileimage"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/BodegaMagazine/StaffPhotos/Small/eric-small-profile-photo.jpeg" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="sendername"><a href="/">Jeff
      </a></div>
      <div class="snippet">
      Hello this is a test message</div>
      <div class="delete"><p>DELETE</p></div>
    </div>
```

http://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your profile picture is 40x40, and the nearest *positioned* parent is `.mail`, which is also 40px. The profile pics *immediate parent* (`.leftprofileimage`) was not explicitly positioned,  so that's probably where the confusion lays. This codepen simply adds rules to `.leftprofileimage` to make it the element that profile pic conforms to:

http://codepen.io/sean9999/pen/xypBb